# Outlook VBA, display title in MsgBox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written the following module to display the Subject of an email that is currently open in Outlook, in a MsgBox.

Outlook 2010. Version 14.0.7140.5002.

I am getting a run-time error '424'  Object Required.

With the debugger highlighting:

```
Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

Code is below:

```
Sub ShowTitle()

    Dim objMail As Object
    Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Dim Title As String
    Set objMail = objItem.Subject

    Title = objItem
    MsgBox (Title)

End Sub
```

Comment: declare objItem I do not see that

Comment: Did you initialize the objApp variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub ShowTitle()

Dim objMail As Object
Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

Dim Title As String
Title = objItem.Subject

MsgBox (Title)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowTitle()

    'Dim objApp as Outlook.Application
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim Title As String

    ' If exclusively in Outlook there is no need for objApp
    'Set objApp = Outlook.Application
    'Set objItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    ' or simpler
    'Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    ' or simplest
    Set objItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    If objItem is mailitem then
        Title = objItem.Subject
        MsgBox (Title)
    End if

    'Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Diane Poremsky over at Slipstick answered this one well in [this article](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/outlook-vba-work-with-open-item-or-select-item/). Per her answer, make one module that contains this function:

```
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing 
End Function
```

Then, also per her answer, call that function with this line in your macro:

```
Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
```

So, modifying your code, I made a second macro like this, which works for me:

```
Sub subjectLine()

    Dim Title As String

    Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()

    Title = objItem.subject

    MsgBox (Title)

End Sub
```

This way, you can run subjectLine() on either a selected email or an open email.